# Find a and b where a sum is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We let a>0 and b>0 and  we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^n-a^n$. We have to find all values a,b>0 where $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^n-a^n$ is convergent.
I think I can use that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n < \infty , \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n < \infty \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (b_n-a_n) < \infty. $$.
And I think $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n$ is convergent if a<1 and b<1? It will make sense. But how can I show it?

Comment: Is term of series $a_n$ of $a^n$? Also, check what happens if $a = b = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they are $a^n$ and $b^n$ instead of $a_n$ and $b_n$.
A power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$ converges if $|a|<1$. Since it is given that $a>0$, $\forall a\in [0,1)$, the series converges. Take another convergent series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty b^n$ where $b\in[0,1)$. Now, since they both are convergent since $a\wedge b\in[0,1)$, their difference is also convergent since the sum is finite in both cases.