# Find all values for a and b where the series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find all values of $a,b>0$ for which the series converge. I know that a geometric series converges if $|r| < 1$ but how can I find all the values for which the series converges in general?

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a^{n} - b^{n}) $$

Comment: I am fairly sure that I have seen the same question yesterday.

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3672953/42969.

Comment: I wonder if it's someone's homework, or takehome exam? It is exam season ... hopefully it's not an exam, but it seems like too much of a coincidence to have the same very specific question two days in a row

Comment: Thanks Martin R, I didn't see the thread that was already posted. To Mukerjee, I think I might be following the same math course as the author of the post from yesterday but due to the coronavirus we are all bound to our homestudies hence the lack of communication. Sorry about that...